# Infer type based on a string in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code,

```
function returnValue(key: string) {
  return { [key]: key }
}

const test = returnValue('try')
```

When you hover over `test`, the tooltip is like this:

[image]

Can we make the `[x: string]` part inferred from the string we are passing in? Something like this:

[image]  (It is a mock type, does not mean I solved it...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly your question, since it's not clear to me which *value* should `key` have.

It doesn't come to my mind a way to do this without casting, but using the `as` you can do this using generics, extending string (while stille keeping completely dynamic typings):

```
function returnValue<T extends string>(key: T) {
  return { [key]: key } as { [K in T]: T };
}

const test = returnValue('try')
```

Comment: that `as` is not ideal, but in a logic where we could be sure what we are doing, this is a pretty good workaround! Thanks